# iOS 7 See Through Window

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to make an app that lets you display the homescreen background in the background of an app. (Similar to the way it's done in the default Passbook and Reminders app)

I couldn't find any API or figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
GA

Comment: I don't think you can access the homescreen setting since its stored as part of the phone's settings. Unless, the background is in a photo album in which case they'd have to select it.

Comment: There is no solution that allow your app in the App Store. There are solutions that use private APIs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for this -- there are private APIs to achieve this but they are private for a reason :D